# How can I average out a certain range of keyframes?

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

For my Blender rig, I have a bunch of parts that are animated. I want to average out the keyframes so each keyframe is at an equal distance from the other. So for instance I have 15 animated keyframes, I want each animated keyframe to be far from each other by say 5 keyframes.

Is this doable?

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to dope sheet
   [image]
2. Click on the first key frame so that the cusroser is set to that
   place
   [image]
3. select the keyframes that needs to be evenly space out, can use "B"
   to drag select area or any other selection
   [image]
4. Press "S" to scale 
   [image]
5. and **input number "5"** if you wish to **evenly space out** all
   keys with interval of 5 frames
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go into the *Graph Editor*, you should be able to <kbd>B</kbd>ox select a vertical column of keyframes. From there, key <kbd>G</kbd>, then  <kbd>X</kbd>, then move the keyframes to the desired time (in frames).

Alternatively, if they are already evenly spaced and you simply want to increase the increment, <kbd>B</kbd>ox select all the keyframes and key <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>X</kbd>, then a value (maybe <kbd>5</kbd> if they are 1 frame apart and you want them to be 5 frames apart).

Hope this helps and happy Blending!

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understood your answer, it seems to me that you are suggesting to select a set of keyframes and move them back and forth in time through the Graph Editor, whilst my request is finding a way to select all the desired keyframes and have them separated by a certain amount of frames automatically